# TYPO3 - Add flexform to my own extension

Tags: fluid, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I am building my own extension.
I have found this page about adding Flexform to the Extension
https://gist.github.com/alrnz/c0f00b196d378f5b9150

And in my ext_tables.php i have this:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerPlugin(
    $_EXTKEY,
    'Xlsxtotables',
    'XLSX to tables'
);

// Include flex forms
$pluginSignature = str_replace('_', '', $_EXTKEY) . '_' .    'xlsxtotables'; // from registerPlugin(...)
$TCA['tt_content']['types']['list']['subtypes_addlist']   [$pluginSignature] = 'pi_flexform';
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addPiFlexFormValue(
    $pluginSignature,    
    'FILE:EXT:' . $_EXTKEY . '/Configuration/FlexForms/flexform_xlsxtotables.xml'
);
```

I know that the XML-file is in the right place, but I do not get anyting from it in TYPO3 backend.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Try replace

```
$pluginSignature = str_replace('_', '', $_EXTKEY) . '_' .    'xlsxtotables';
```

by

```
$extensionName = strtolower(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::underscoredToUpperCamelCase($_EXTKEY));
$pluginSignature = $extensionName.'_'.'xlsxtotables';
```

And dont forget to empty your general cache before you see a change with your flexform.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code in **ext_tables.php** file

```
$pluginName = 'Pi1'; // Give Your Plugin Nmae
$pluginSignature = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]/', '', strtolower($_EXTKEY)) . '_' . strtolower($pluginName);

// FlexForm configuration
$TCA['tt_content']['types']['list']['subtypes_addlist'][$pluginSignature] = 'pi_flexform';
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addPiFlexFormValue(
    $pluginSignature,
    'FILE:EXT:' . $_EXTKEY . '/Configuration/FlexForms/flexformname.xml'
);
```

For Adding Flexforms in **One or More Front-end plugins** you can use Below code in **ext_tables.php**

```
$extensionName = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::underscoredToUpperCamelCase($_EXTKEY);
$frontendpluginName = 'xxx'; //Your Front-end Plugin Name
$pluginSignature = strtolower($extensionName) . '_'.strtolower($frontendpluginName);
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['list']['subtypes_addlist'][$pluginSignature] = 'pi_flexform';
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addPiFlexFormValue($pluginSignature, 'FILE:EXT:' . $_EXTKEY . '/Configuration/FlexForms/xyz.xml');
```